# Implementing UI changes in multiple fragments - Simultaneously

Tags: android, android-fragments

In my application, I use a single activity and use this as container for all the fragments in the application. I have a base fragment in my application. All the fragments in my application extends this base fragment.

Now here is my dilemma over going ahead and implementing a certain requirement. I have a logout functionality in my application. When I press logout button in the actionbar, corresponding UI changes need to be reflected in many of the fragments in the application simultaneously. Changes need to be reflected only when I get 'success' response from the logout webserice.

How to trigger UI changes in fragments simultaneously is my question.

I can think of two approaches.

1) Create an interface with a method onlogoutsuccess(). Make the Base fragment to implement this interface. Override the implementation in all the fragments(remember every fragment extends base fragment). In the container activity, get the instance of all the fragments whose UI need to be changed and invoke the onlogoutsuccess() method in these fragments.

2) Send a local broadcast when logout webservice returns success. Make the fragments register dynamically for this broadcast and do the required changes in UI from onreceive method.

Which of these is the better approach. Would appreciate, if I can have clarity on the pros and cons of these 2 approaches, if any.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the third possibility : use [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) or a similar library.

The disadvantage of EventBus is that your code becomes complex to understand (or I don't know how to use it properly, which is very likely as well).

Therefore, I would go with your first proposition.

Comment: I'm a bit fan of the EventBus and would be the solution that I would use.  Just a few lines of code and you can send messages to multiple fragments and background services.  Much cleaner than creating interfaces and callbacks.

Comment: Many thanks for introducing EventBus. Will certainly look into the possibility of using it. @Gordak is there any specific reason you do not prefer approach 2?

Comment: Well, for the same reasons the roarster mentionned: speed.

Comment: Now that I think about it, you should care about the state of the Fragments at the moment the logout is done. Imagine the user press logout and then switches to another Application or the screen reorientates itself. In this case, the Fragments might not be in a good state to make the modifications it should do. 

If you use EventBus, there is a possibility to store some of the event and to receive them when you subscribe, which in that case makes things easier.

Answer (score 0):

I like the first method the most because I've had bad experience in the past with broadcasts just generally being slow. By using an interface it makes it a lot cleaner, but you will have to keep track of the Fragments you have in your app. If you don't dynamically create any this shouldn't be a problem but it can become a nuisance if you do.

The second method would probably require the least amount of effort. Each Fragment will just start a BroadcastReceiver `onResume` and stop it on `onPause`. Then you just send off the logout intent and don't care about who it gets to - you just assume it gets to the right people(kinda like [UDP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol)). Like I said earlier, it can be a little delayed, but if you don't mind too much then maybe it's for you.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Unfortunately, does not have enough reputation to upvote. Will wait for some more answers to come to a logical conclusion.